# Speaker Diarization is disabled even for supported languages in Google Speech-to-Text API V2

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech, automatic-speech-recognition

I'm trying to use Google's [Speech-to-Text v2 API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs) for transcription and speaker diarization.

Per [this supported languages page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/speech-to-text-supported-languages), I should be able to create a Recognizer using the "long" model for the language "en-US" that supports diarization.

And yet every time I try to create such a Recognizer (I've tried using both the UI and the API), I get an error message. In the API it says "Recognizer does not support feature: speaker_diarization" and in the UI it shows the attached message:

[image]

Am I missing something here? Why can't speaker diarization be applied?

Comment: I have same issue, even if I try via API

Comment: The same issue persists, 6 months later.